# What is probability of 3 incorrect multiple choice questions out of 6 multiple choice questions?

Tags: math, probability, probability-theory

A BCS Level 2 test has 6 multiple choice questions with four choices with one correct answer each. If we just randomly guess on each of the 6 questions, what is the probability that you get exactly 3 questions will not be correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. [Self-answers are welcome here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but questions still need to be on-topic. Your _answer_ has some code in it, but your _question_ is a math question and has nothing to do with programming. It is very off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about a binomial distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

For any single question you have p_wrong = 3/4 since there's only 1/4 correct. You are then asking about P(3 wrong | 6 trials) "probability of 3 wrong given 6 trials".

P(3 wrong | 6) = (6 choose 3)(3/4)^3(1/4)^3

6 choose 3 = 6! / 3!(6-3)! = 4*5*6/(3*2*1) = 20

So then 20*(3/4)^3(1/4)^3 = 0.1318359375

**edit** You can simulate this in Python via:

```py
import random
def sim(k, N):
  trial_count = 0
  for i in range(N):
    # simulate a 6 question test
    test_count = 0
    for j in range(6):
      # we'll say you got it right if you get a 1, else it's wrong
      c = random.randint(1,4)
      if c == 1:
        test_count += 1
    # after the test see how many they got right, if it's k
    if test_count == k:
      trial_count += 1
  # after all the trials return the probability
  return trial_count/N
# getting exactly 3 wrong on a 6 Q test is the same as exactly 3 right
print(sim(3, 1_000_000)
```

or a little shorter in [APL](https://tryapl.org/) ;)

```
sim←{(+/⍺=+/1=?⍵ 6⍴(6×⍵)/4)÷⍵}
3 sim 1e6
```